# Convert statements into prolog code

Tags: prolog

Hey 
I 'm trying to convert the following statements into prolog code, but I'm not sure if I did it correctly.

1-everybody who respects himself is respected by others:

```
   respects(x,respects(x)) :- respects(y,x)).
```

2-john respects herself:

```
respectsherself(john).
respects(john,respectsherself(john)).
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In prolog variables must start with a capital letter so look out for that.

Everybody who respects himself is respected by others. I think you need some basic facts such as who respects who. Then you can declare a rule that says X is respected by others is implied by X respecting Himself.

```
 respects(john, mary). %john respects mary
 respects(john, john). %john respects himself
 respects(X, Y) :- respectedbyothers(Y). %X respects Y if Y is respected by others
 respectedbyothers(X):-respects(X, X).
```

Comment: It would be nice if `respects(ben, john).` gave `true` because `ben` is an Other.

Answer (score 0):

An optimization:
%respects(A,B) means A is respected by B
respects(john,john).
respects(X,_):-respects(X,X).
?

Don't you just love prolog :)